# Parallel lines not showing on my map document (QGIS; v.parallel function)

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-processing, parallel-lines

Weird issue: I am trying to use **v.parallel** to draw a line parallel to a single line layer I have. It processes without issue, but the parallel line does not appear on the map. The curious thing is that I can click zoom to layer and it zooms to the area where the line SHOULD appear...it's just not physically there.

These are the parameters I set. Why is it not showing?

[image: v.parallel params]

Also it has no apparent ability to loop through several lines if I wanted say, 10 parallel lines at an equal spacing. Do I really have to manually do each parallel line?

Comment: Have you checked that the output layer is on the top and not somehow covered by another layer?

Comment: Yeah, it's at the top of the drawing order!